# On hereditarily reflexive Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It was proved by W.B. Johnson and H.P. Rosenthal [[Studia Math. 43 (1972), 77–92]](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm43/sm4317.pdf)
that every Banach space $X$ with $X^{**}$ separable is *hereditarily reflexive*:
every infinite dimensional closed subspace of $X$ contains an infinite dimensional
reflexive subspace.

Suppose that $X$ is separable and $X^{**}/X$ reflexive. Is $X$ hereditarily reflexive?

Of course, we would have a positive answer if each infinite dimensional closed subspace of such a space $X$ contains an infinite dimensional subspace $Y$ with $Y^{**}$ separable.

Comment: Gowers' dichotomy theorem reduces to the case that $$ is HI. Have you asked Argyros whether there exists a hereditarily non reflexive HI space $X$ with $X^{**}/X$ reflexive?

Comment: I have looked at Spiros A. Argyros, Alexander D. Arvanitakis, Andreas G. Tolias.
Saturated extensions, the attractors method and Hereditarily James Tree Spaces. pp. 1-90 in "Methods in Banach space theory". 
J.M.F. Castillo and W.B. Johnson eds. Cambridge University Press, 2006.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has a negative answer:

Following the idea in Bill Johnson's comment, I looked at the work of Argyros. In this [**paper**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2392) (see the reference below), there are several examples of hereditarily indecomposable Banach spaces containing no infinite dimensional reflexive subspaces.

One of these spaces $X$ has the additional property that $X^{**}/X$  is isomorphic to $\ell_2(\Gamma)$ with $\Gamma$ uncountable: see Proposition 5.4 in the paper.

**[reference]** S.A. Argyros, A.D. Arvanitakis, A.G. Tolias.
*Saturated extensions, the attractors method and Hereditarily James Tree Spaces.*
pp. 1-90 in "Methods in Banach space theory". J.M.F. Castillo and W.B. Johnson eds.
London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser. 337, Cambridge University Press, 2006.

Comment: Just one of the many amazing examples constructed by Argyros et al.